# Selenium Python: traceback.format_exc() error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium Python: `traceback.format_exc()` error:
(Sorry, I'm new to Python, struggling with object and method stuff)

Here is the commandline error:

```
Line ## in LogErrorDetials
LogErrorMessage = LogErrorMessage + "\n\n" + traceback.format_exc()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 256, in format_exc
return "".join(format_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, chain=chain))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 181, in format_exception
return list(_format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 146, in _format_exception_iter
for value, tb in values:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
context = exc.__context__

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__context__'
```

The offending line:

```
LogErrorMessage = LogErrorMessage + "\n\n" + traceback.format_exc()
```

How can I check that the `traceback.format_exc()` will work before calling it, or how can I check the attribute `__context__` is not `NoneType` (if that is better)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like - [Issue 23003](http://bugs.python.org/issue23003) . It says -

> This regression was introduced in Python 3.0.

I think this is fixed in Python 3.4 (According to the issue page) . I do not see any workarounds specified there.

You can try using `sys.exc_info()` to get the exception and then pass that into `traceback.format_exception()` -

```
a = sys.exc_info()
traceback.format_exception(*a)
```

Please note, `traceback.format_exception()` returns a list, to convert it into a string, use -

```
''.join(traceback.format_exception(*a))
```

Comment: Are you saying I should always get the exception and then pass that into traceback.format_exception() with:
a = sys.exc_info()
traceback.format_exception(*a)

or should I check something first?

Comment: Untill the fix is there , you may need that.

Comment: @MatthewCox No need to check anything, just always get the exception and pass that into `format_exception()`

Comment: This
TB = sys.exc_info()
LogErrorMessage = LogErrorMessage + "\n\n" + traceback.format_exception(*TB)

 is producing the error:
Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: Yes, `traceback.format_exception()` returns a list , use - `''.join(traceback.format_exception(*a))` . Complete - `LogErrorMessage = LogErrorMessage + "\n\n" + ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*a))`